# Swift: Cannot convert value of type 'Int16' to expected argument type 'AnyObject?'

Tags: ios, swift

I get the following error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'Int16' to expected argument type 'AnyObject?'

on the line

```
person.setValue(Time, forKey: "Time")
```

when I run this app. The frame of the function was taken from [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/115695/getting-started-with-core-data-tutorial) and changed from `String` to `Int16`, as well as the entity and attribute names.

```
var people = [NSManagedObject]()

   func saveName(Time: Int16) {
    //1
    let appDelegate =
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

    //2
    let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Person",
                                                    inManagedObjectContext:managedContext)

    let person = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!,
                                 insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

    //3
    person.setValue(Time, forKey: "Time")

    //4
    do {
        try managedContext.save()
        //5
        people.append(person)
    } catch let error as NSError  {
        print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of calling `setValue`, better define managed object subclasses for your entities and then access their properties. That is much less error-prone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error says, `Int16` isn't an object in Swift, and therefore can't be used in `setValue(forKey:)`, which expects an object. Try wrapping it in an `NSNumber`, like so:

```
person.setValue(NSNumber(short: Time), forKey: "Time")
```

Comment: This fixes the issues, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to use an Int16, you cannot hand that off directly to Objective-C as an object the way you can with bridged number types like Int. Swift numbers are not Objective-C objects, and Swift is not going to help you except with simple numbers like Int and Double. For an Int16, *you* must wrap it up as an NSNumber, yourself.

Comment: ah I see now, im new to programming sorry. Thanks for the reply